# How to set a default format for a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-formats, customization

I created a custom post type for my blog, to allow easier separation of content. This new post type supports different post formats, but most of them will be galleries.

```
register_post_type('atelier',
    array(
    'label' => 'L\'Atelier',
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'post-formats')
    )
);
```

I saw that it is possible in Settings -> Writing to set the default post format for posts, is it possible to do the same for my newly created post type?

Comment: Probably best to refer to this question/answer. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32480/custom-post-formats-for-custom-post-types Basically, create a custom post type template and just style them through that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to [modify the global Default Post Format setting, via `Dashboard -> Settings -> Writing`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Writing_Screen#Writing_Settings).

Note that this setting is *global*, so it would set the default for *all* post types that support Post Formats.

If you have no need of post formats for blog Posts, you could simply enable post-format support *only* for your custom post type, by *removing* post-format support for blog posts:

```
<?php
remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'post-formats' );
?>
```

(Untested, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.)

Answer (score 9):

You can handle this using the `option_default_post_format` filter:

```
add_filter( 'option_default_post_format', 'slimline_default_post_format' );

/**
 * Posts of post_type_1 will be asides by default, but all other post types
 * will be the default set on the Settings > Writing admin panel
 */
function slimline_default_post_format( $format ) {
    global $post_type;

    return ( 'post_type_1' === $post_type ? 'aside' : $format );
}
```

If you want to set up the filter for multiple custom post types, I'd edit the function to use a switch statement, like so:

```
function slimline_default_post_format( $format ) {
    global $post_type;

    switch( $post_type ) {
        case 'post_type_1' :
            $format = 'aside';
            break;
        case 'post_type_2' :
            $format = 'quote';
            break;
    }

    return $format;
}
```

Comment: This answer actually addresses the original question!

Answer (score 0):

For starters used to a different PHP syntax: The code blocks in @MichaelDozark's excellent answer can also be written as:

```
/*
 * Posts of post_type_1 will be asides by default, but all other post types
 * will be the default set on the Settings > Writing admin panel
 */
add_filter( 'option_default_post_format', 'custom_default_post_format' );
function custom_default_post_format( $format ) {
    global $post_type;

    if( $post_type == 'post_type_1' ) {
        $format = 'aside';
    }

    return $format;
}
```

And:

```
add_filter( 'option_default_post_format', 'custom_default_post_format' );
function custom_default_post_format( $format ) {
    global $post_type;

    if( $post_type == 'post_type_1' ) {
        $format = 'aside';
    } elseif ( $post_type == 'post_type_2' ) {
        $format = 'quote';
    }

    return $format;
}
```

***Source:** [Examples for the `switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) in the PHP Manual.*