# How to add gallery support to a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, gallery, post-type-support

I've created a custom post type.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_post_type' );
function my_custom_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'my_custom_post_type',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'custom Posts' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'custom Post' )
      ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'capability_type' => array("custom Post", "custom Posts"),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments' )
    )
  );
}
```

If I add any images on the editor it displays as it is on the front end.
but If add any gallery it displays as some thing like this: `[gallery link="file" ids="581,580,575"]`

what I have to do to show the gallery for this custom post type?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Post Formats for Custom Post Types](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32480/custom-post-formats-for-custom-post-types)

Comment: Do you mean that the gallery shortcode is not executed? Can you post the code you are using for the front end output?